# Dynamically create new instance of a variable in Java

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two class that i need to perform a same operation using hibernate.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
class User {

    @Id
    public int id;

    String user;
    //etc...
}


@Entity
@Table(name="groups")
class Group {

    @Id
    public int id;

    String group_name;
    //etc...
}
```

I have a hibernate class to save data

```
public Hibernate {

    public static void save(User user) {
        Session session = ... opne my session
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

        // save
        session.save(user);

        tx.commit();
        session.close();

    }
}
```

Now I want to save group but I want to use the same function but I cannot pass a Group

I tried to pass

```
public static void save(Class myClass) {
```

but then I get some errors How can I pass dynamically a class so it work?

so my code will be:

> User user = new User().... Hibernate.save(user); // this will save a
>   user in the user table
>
> Group group = new Group().... Hibernate.save(group); // this will save
>   a group in the group table

Comment: Time for some [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you just have to replace `public static void save(User user)` with `public static void save(Object object)`

Sidenote:

Also, if you don't want to pass every object to persist then you can make your entities implement a marker interface and receive that interface in the formal arguments of `save`.

Something like this:

```
@Override
public <T extends Base> T find(Class<T> baseClass, Long id) {
    if (baseClass == null || id == null) {
        throw new DaoLevelException("Entity class or id cannot be null");
    }
    // code for finding with id
}

@Override
public void save(Base base) {
    if (base == null) {
        throw new DaoLevelException("object passed for saving cannot be null");
    }
    // code for persist 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, there are pretty "standard" patterns for database access.  For example the "DAO" - data access object and also the "Repository" (in Spring).  But if you choose to instead have a utility class with static methods (not recommended), you can either create a second `save()` method, the second one would take instances of `Group` (standard method name overloading in Java), or you can have both `User` and `Group` classes inherit from some common base class for your entities and then have a single `save()` method that takes instances of the common base class.

Comment: so If I have 100 tables, I need to create 100 save()? so not recommended... what should I do?

Comment: As I wrote: create a common base class and then you have a single save() method.  OR, as a hack (e.g., not recommended) just change your save() method to take Object.